# как правильно прочитать в JSONObject не по ключу, а по порядку

Tags: json, kotlin

есть json вот такой:

```
response: {
    count: 18,
    items: {
        2: {},
        3: {},
        4: {},
        5: {},
        6: {},
        7: {},
        9: {},
        10: {},
        11: {},
        12: {},
        14: {},
        15: {},
        16: {},
        17: {},
        18: {},
        19: {},
        20: {},
        21: {}
    }
}
```

проблема в том, что нет, например, номера 8, сразу после 7 идёт 9, и эти номера могут при следующий загрузке поменяться.

как прочитать не по имени ключа, а просто по порядку?

Comment: Насколько я знаю - никак. Порядок свойств в объекте не гарантируется. А нельзя использовать сортировку или преобразовать в массив?

Comment: @XelaNimed, можно. Но не значения напрямую, а получить список ключей и по нему пройтись. https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#keys()

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja  согласен - не правильно выразился.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  1: "a",
  3: "b",
  2: "c",
  6: "d",
  4: "e",
  9: "f",
  12: "g",
  7: "h"
};
Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}).forEach(function(objectKey) {
  // здесь можно обрабатывать элементы по порядку
  console.log("object key: " + objectKey + ", obj[key]: " + obj[objectKey]);
});
```